# Deleting multiple data points from .csv file through QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a .csv file with points in North America, but I only want to focus on a section through North America that excludes places such as Alaska and Greenland.

I've selected the points below, but the Delete Selected button is greyed out. Is there any way to delete these points through QGIS or will I have to edit my .csv file and import it again?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j32jV.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSV file is only displayed in the workspace. If you want to edit it with QGIS, export these points to a Shapefile, as that you can edit in QGIS.

Otherwise, as you said, edit the CSV manually then import again

Comment: I just did this, but I'm still having the same problem. I saved it as a shapefile, but I can't delete the new points (after loading the shapefile)

edit: nevermind, toggled editing and now it works